# create an array of promises for Promise.all

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have an array of file paths, and I want to read all files inside Promise.all, and then perform some tasks.

```
var files = ["./file1.txt", "./file2.txt"]

Promise.all(files.forEach(file=>{ /* read file content */}))
```

Comment: It’s not clear what you need to do here because you don’t show how you are reading the files. Does the function you are calling to read / request files return a promise?

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `Array.map`:

```
var files = ["./file1.txt", "./file2.txt"]

Promise.all(files.map(async file=>{ /* read file content */}))
```

If you don't want it to be an async function but want it to return a promise, that's fine too

```
var files = ["./file1.txt", "./file2.txt"]

Promise.all(files.map(file=>{ /* read file content, return a promise */}))
```

[edit] here's an example using my preferred file interface, fse - its' just fs but with promises:

```
var files = ["./file1.txt", "./file2.txt"]

Promise.all(files.map(file=>{ 
    return fse.readFile(file, 'utf-8');
})).then(results => {
    // results is an array of strings of the contents of each file
})
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra

Comment: `fs` comes with promisefied methods as well after `Node 10.0.0` [fsPromises.readFile](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_readfile_path_options)

Comment: oh, didn't know that. Thanks @AZ_